# FTP Server connection closes in about 5 minutes

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

> i'm using ***Apache commons-net 3.6*** library in java

I'm making a program that accesses the ftp server at a certain interval-cycle and receives files(only one file)

When I first run the program, it works without any problem, but About 5 minutes later, when I access the file again, I print out an error message..

(If the interval-cycle is less than 5 minutes, it will operate periodically)

Of course, the connection to the server is only made at the beginning of the first

```
error message : org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: FTP response 421 received.  Server closed connection.
```

I think it's a ftp-connection timeout problem

So the way I tried

```
FTPClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(sec);
FTPClient.setConnectTimeout(ms);
FTPClient.setDataTimeout(ms);
FTPClient.connect();
FTPClient.setSoTimeout(ms);
```

but, not working.. Error messages are still output.

Please help me :(

Comment: You should close the connection when you're finished with it each time. You can't rely on the server to keep its end open for you.

Comment: @user207421 Can you explain to me why you can't keep the server open?

Comment: You asked about the same thing again in  [Can the FTP client control FTP server time-out settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57352335/can-the-ftp-client-control-ftp-server-time-out-settings)

Comment: Because you can't rely on the server to keep its end open for you. I already said that. This is exactly what you are experiencing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the server is deciding to close the FTP connection after a period (5 minutes) of inactivity.  This is done as a way to manage resources on the server side.  Idle session are using serve memory, kernel resources, port numbers, and so on.  If idle sessions are not booted of, there is a risk that the server will run out of them ... and stop working.

Check the FTP server logs.  You may need to change the server-side logging level ... temporarily ... to get more clues.

If this is the problem, changing client-side timeouts etc, using keep-alives, etc won't help.   Indeed, if you check the documentation, most of the params that you have been tweaking are about the client timing out the server, not the other way around.

Solutions:

- Change the FTP server configuration to allow session to be idle for longer
- On the client side, send periodic requests to make the serve think that the session is still being used.

Comment: Can't the client control the connection timeout of the FTP server by using java code?

Comment: Nope.   That would be counter productive from the POV of the server admins.