# Can the FTP client control FTP server time-out settings?

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am using **Apache Commons-Net** library in Java

What I want is to set the connection time-out of the FTP-server on the client stage
using java-code

example :

If I look at the FTP server's vsftpd.conf settings file,

there is a `idle_session_timeout=600` setting

I wonder if this idle time-out can be controlled by FTP-client using java code

The method below, which I tried but not all worked

```
FTPClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(sec);
FTPClient.setConnectTimeout(ms);
FTPClient.setDataTimeout(ms);
FTPClient.connect();
FTPClient.setSoTimeout(ms);
```

Please help me :)

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by doing this?  If you want to close after arbitrary idle time then maybe set  up a timer thread

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The FTP client cannot control the settings of the FTP server.

But what you are asking looks more like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) where X is probably that you want to prevent the server to close an idle connection an Y is the idea of a solution you came up with: controlling the servers timeout from the client side. Only, this solution will not work.

Instead you need to tackle the real reason why the server is closing the connection: because of no activity from the client. This problem can be tackled simply by the client interacting with the server. This way is even [documented](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html). To cite:

> You should keep in mind that the FTP server may choose to prematurely close a connection if the client has been idle for longer than a given time period (usually 900 seconds). ... You may **avoid server disconnections while the client is idle by periodically sending NOOP commands to the server**.

Comment: Documents show that noop commands are sent to the ftp server via the setControlKeepAliveTimeout (Sec) method to avoid idle states.But the method doesn’t work properly.

Comment: `setControlKeepAliveTimeout` is not to keep the connection alive when idle. It servers as a workaround for routers that close the seemingly idle control connection during lengthy transfers: *"FTP servers know that the control connection is in use, so won't close it through lack of activity, but it's a lot harder for network routers to know that the control and data connections are associated with each other. Some routers may treat the control connection as idle, and disconnect it if the transfer over the data connection takes longer than the allowable idle time for the router."*

Comment: If you want to keep the connection alive, when really idle, you need to call `sendNoOp` explicitly in regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

I used the WireShark to see if the config of setControlKeepAliveTimeout() work,  and found than it only works when ftp uploading or downloading files

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).