# FTPClient - Send Noop to a FTP server in a stream method

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I'm using `FTPClient` (Apache Commons Net)

I know that `FTPClient` provides two methods to avoid the idle state of the FTP server:

1. `ftpClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(300)` – Send a noop every five minutes
2. `ftpClient.sendNoOp()` – send a noop a one-time event

I tried to use `setControlKeepAliveTimeout()`

But the official FTPClient document On `setControlKeepAliveTimeout`....

> Please note: this does not apply to the methods where the user is
>   responsible for writing or reading the data stream, i.e.
>   `retrieveFileStream(String)`, `storeFileStream*(String)` and the other
>   `xxxFileStream` methods

My program uses only `retrieveFileStream`, which is not applied to `setControlKeepAliveTimeout` .

Is there no way to operate the noop repeatedly in a stream method, not a one-time event, like a `sendNoOp`?

Comment: I guess that this is your related question, posted using a different account: [Can the FTP client control FTP server time-out settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57352335/850848)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing that will do it for you, the comment you have quoted is clear about that.

You have to code it yourself:
Read the stream and while doing that, in regular intervals, call the [`FTPClient.sendNoOp`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#sendNoOp()).